# search mysql two date fields containing single date

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains fields start_date and end_date both in datetime format.

What I need to do is find all rows where a certain date falls between the start and end dates.

For example if I have these rows in my table I want to get all rows where start to end date would include 2011-12-08

```
start_date          end_date
2011-12-01 09:00:00 2011-12-04 17:00:00
2011-12-07 15:00:00 2011-12-09 16:00:00
2011-12-08 10:30:00 2011-12-08 14:00:00
```

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Using both Nick and Angelo's answers the final sql I have is

SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE (
'2011-12-08'
BETWEEN `start_date`
AND `end_date`
)
OR (
date( `start_date` ) >= '2011-12-08'
AND date( `end_date` ) <= '2011-12-08'
)

Thanks

Comment: that does not look like a good solution. if you want to combine nicks and my answer use SELECT * FROM table WHERE '2011-12-08' BETWEEN date(start_date) AND date(end_date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table
where '2011-12-08' between date(start_date) and date(end_date)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick.

That returns me row two but I also need it to include row three.

Comment: that won't return lines where start_date and end_date both are on the same day.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table     
WHERE date(start_date) >= '2011-12-08' AND date(end_date) <= '2011-12-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

Small improvement, so an existing index can be used. Using  `DATE(start_date)` and `DATE(end_date)` forbids any index use.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableX
WHERE start_date < '2011-12-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  AND '2011-12-08' <= end_date
```